# Burninate the pangram tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

Do we really need a tag for [pangram](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pangram) puzzles? It's very very specific, and surely there aren't many puzzles that can be posed on this topic. Something more general should be usable.

That said, there doesn't seem to *be* any more general tag at the moment for puzzles like the single one tagged [pangram](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pangram), except maybe [english](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/english). The tag descriptions for [language](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/language) and [letter-sequence](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/letter-sequence) don't really fit the bill. Maybe the creation of a new tag is called for as well?

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with [pangram](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pangram)? It's a tag I can imagine someone searching because they learned about pangrams and are interested in puzzles related to them. Just because there's only one puzzle now doesn't mean there won't be more.

In contrast, I think [language](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/language) and [letter-sequence](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/letter-sequence) are too vague to be useful. Can you imagine someone thinking "I want to filter puzzles that are about letter sequences."?

I see what you're getting at though with a tag about sentences having restrictions on their sequence of letters (pangrams, palindromes, etc), which could be a useful tag, though I can't think of a good category name.